# How to enter a door?

Tags: blaster-master

Sorry for the seemingly trivial question, but none of the YouTube vids I've watched on the subject have revealed anything.

As if it weren't bad enough that the Select button is required to exit the tank (against common NES convention - although I could also fault the convention, for limiting the scope of that button to menu selection only... in most games).

But let's get on with it. There is a door, and I am in front of it. Yet I have no idea how to enter it. What button combo am I supposed to press?

On the other hand, if this is a matter of me lacking a certain key required to pass, then that's fine. Just give me some user-feedback to indicate that. I'm pretty sure that's *not* the case here, though.

[image: Master Blaster - Enter Door]

In most games of this era a simple UP on the D-pad would suffice. But here we have something of a usability mystery. Please give me a clue... or even a totally in-depth explanation.  ;-)

Comment: Excellent title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blaster Master is a little different; you need to press DOWN on the d-pad to enter doors, whether on foot or in the tank.

Comment: LOLOLOLOL...（笑） thank you! I did not expect the answer to be so (1) simple, (2) stupid [that is to say, diametrically opposed to the "UP" convention], and (3) quick! It's nice to know there are still enough people in the know, to share knowledge on the retro.

Comment: This ... is a weird question. I mean, seeing as you already know controls were "unconventional" (select to get out of the tank), it's surprising that you didn't try the down button. I guess it was more a hassle to come here and ask a question uploading your screen cap that to mash every button and see what happen ...

Comment: @Fana My question is both *unreasonable* and *reasonable*, when taken into consideration that the context of era is different - meaning that back in "the day" one would have had no other means than to try every possible button combination, or resort to a Nintendo Power guide book. While in the present I was able to post a question on SE and get a response rather quickly. So which is the better strategy? In any case, it worked out for me. bmurrell30 was like "press DOWN" and I did that. Yay! All's good.  :-D

Comment: @Mentalist I mean, I see his point.  NES has a total of 10 input buttons.  Considering the answer was as simple as _down on the d-pad_, it begs the question of what exactly did you try before posting here?  You simply tried _up_ then came here when it didn't work?

Comment: @Steve-o169 I was just surprised that none of the methods one would normally expect to work worked. Like, "UP doesn't work... A doesn't work... B doesn't work... various combinations of those don't work... are you kidding me?" I probably should've been a little more patient.  :-p (P.S. classic NES has 8 buttons, so you must have one of those controllers with the additional AA and BB turbo buttons, or whatever they're called, that fire twice.)